# Get value from IsolatedStorageSetting in windows phone7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I am using visual studio2010 and its windows phone 7 application

I have created addpet.xaml and mypet.xaml.
Created IsolatedStorageSetting object in mypet.cs file

{

```
      public static IsolatedStorageSettings settings=IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

}

I have 5 textboxes and I am storing its value in list item.That list stores in IsolatedStorageSetting object.

{

```
        SaveMypet savepet = new SaveMypet();

        savepet.Name = txt_name.ToString();
        savepet.Birthday = txt_birthday.ToString();
        savepet.FavFood = txt_favouritefood.ToString();
        savepet.DocNo = txt_doctorsno.ToString();
        savepet.VacDate = txt_vacdate.ToString();
        savepet.FavToy = txt_favouritetoy.ToString();
        //   savepet.Image1 = image1.Source;

        listMyPet.Add(savepet);
        settings.Add("iso_listMyPet", listMyPet);
```

}

Now I want to access this object in addpet.cs and cast it to list and then want to assign to listbox.
Like this, I have did but does not work
Created list object in addpet.cs

{

```
     static List<pg_addPet> list_listMyPet = null;
```

}

```
       protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

{

```
       list_listMyPet = (List<pg_addPet>)pg_addPet.settings["iso_mypet_list"];
       listbox_mypet.ItemsSource = list_listMyPet;
```

}

And my SaveMypet class is

```
        public class SaveMypet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public string FavFood { get; set; }
    public string DocNo { get; set; }
    public string VacDate { get; set; }
    public string FavToy { get; set; }
   // public ImageSource  Image1 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: problem is am unable to access IsolatedStorageSetting object in another class

Comment: Do you get an exception? A null value?

Comment: Yes..I am getting KeyNotFoundException.

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Now I am getting 'System.InvalidCastException' at                      list_listMyPet = (List<pg_addPet>)pg_mypet.settings["iso_mypet_list"];

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the `settings` property as `static`. Therefore, you need to use the class name to access it:

```
list_listMyPet = (List<pg_addPet>)pg_mypet.settings["iso_mypet_list"];
```

Comment: Thanks...but still its not working. I am getting exception as 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Now I am getting 'System.InvalidCastException' at above statement

Comment: The KeyNotFoundException just means that there's no element called "iso_mypet_list" in the settings. Just check beforehand by using the `Contains` method: `if pg_mypet.settings.Contains("iso_mypet_list") { ... }`

Comment: And the InvalidCastException means that whatever you've put in "iso_mypet_list" isn't a `List<pg_addPet>`

Comment: InvalidCastException at           list_listMyPet = (List<pg_myPet>)pg_addPet.settings["iso_mypet_list"];

Comment: @RajashriPawar As I said, it means `pg_addPet.settings["iso_mypet_list"]` isn't a `(List<pg_myPet>)`. If you want to know what it is, try putting a breakpoint on it, then use Visual Studio's quickwatch window to see the type of the variable. Or display somewhere (using a messagebox or `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`) the value of `pg_addPet.settings["iso_mypet_list"].GetType()`

Comment: yes I did as you told...It display System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: That means pg_addPet.settings["iso_mypet_list"] contains list... then why InvalidCastException occurs...?  Please help...Thank you

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.List` isn't the full type, you're missing the generic part. Please check the full type name.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IndianPetshop.SaveMypet]

Comment: where IndianPetshop is application name and SaveMypet is class name

Comment: So you have a list of `SaveMyPet` and you're trying to cast it to a list of `pg_addPet`. Hence the invalid cast exception.

Comment: Yeah....thank you so much....but now I am assigning this list to listbox by { listbox_mypet.ItemsSource = pg_addPet.list_listMyPet;}   It only shows IndianPetshop.SaveMypet in listbox

Comment: @RajashriPawar You need to set the `ItemTemplate` property of your listbox. But we're way outside of the scope of your question now. I suggest you mark this one as solved and start a new one.

Comment: Yes sure....thanks...I am using stackoverflow first time...and my problem is solved....its great

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if(!pg_mypet.settings.TryGetValue("iso_mypet_list", out list_listMyPet)) 
{
  list_listMyPet = new List<pg_addPet>();
}
```

This will try to retrieve the value and if if fails it will create an empty list instead.

Comment: Thanks but InvalidCastException occurs at line                                                                                                        if(!pg_mypet.settings.TryGetValue("iso_mypet_list", out list_listMyPet))

Comment: Have you stored something else than a List<pg_addPet> in the settings "iso_mypet_list"? It seems you are getting an object of another type